# is it possible to let the openapi render java enum key and values

Tags: java, openapi

I am using openapi `api "org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.9"` to render the java restful docs, this is server side the enum define:

```
public enum DeviceType {
    IOS(1, "Apple"),
    ANDROID(2, "Android"),
    MINI_APP(3, "Mini App"),
    H5(4, "H5"),
    MAC_DESKTOP(5, "Mac Desktop"),
    LINUX_DESKTOP(6, "Linux Desktop"),
    WINDOWS_DESKTOP(7, "Windows Desktop"),
    GOOGLE_CHROME_EXTENSION(8, "Google Chrome Extension"),
    MACOS(9, "macOS"),
    ;

    @JsonValue
    private Integer key;
    private String value;

    DeviceType(Integer key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    private static final Map<Integer, DeviceType> mappings;

    static {
        Map<Integer, DeviceType> temp = new HashMap<>();
        for (DeviceType courseType : values()) {
            temp.put(courseType.key, courseType);
        }
        mappings = Collections.unmodifiableMap(temp);
    }

    @EnumConvertMethod
    @JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.DELEGATING)
    public static DeviceType resolve(Integer key) {
        return mappings.get(key);
    }
    
    public Integer getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(Integer key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static DeviceType getAppMarkByValue(String value) {
        DeviceType datetimeType = null;
        for (DeviceType type : DeviceType.values()) {
            if (type.name().equals(value)) {
                datetimeType = type;
            }
        }
        return datetimeType;
    }

    public static DeviceType getAppMarkByKey(Integer key) {
        DeviceType datetimeType = null;
        for (DeviceType type : DeviceType.values()) {
            if (type.key.equals(key)) {
                datetimeType = type;
            }
        }
        return datetimeType;
    }
}
```

now the swagger docs show enum like this:

```
deviceType  string
title: device type
example: 1
Enum:
[ IOS, ANDROID, MINI_APP, H5, MAC_DESKTOP, LINUX_DESKTOP, WINDOWS_DESKTOP, GOOGLE_CHROME_EXTENSION, MACOS ]
```

is it possible to return the key and value of the enun in the swagger docs? what should I do to return the key and value pair in docs? this is the rest api define:

```
@PostMapping("/guest/login")
Response<LoginResponse> guestLogin(@RequestBody @Valid FortuneGuestLoginRequest request);

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class FortuneGuestLoginRequest implements Serializable {

    @Schema(title = "code", example = "",hidden = true)
    private String phone;

    @Schema(title = "password", example = "fortune",hidden = true)
    private String password;

    @Schema(title = "logintype", example = "1",hidden = true)
    private LoginType loginType;

    @Schema(title = "type", example = "1")
    private DeviceType deviceType;

    @Schema(title = "id", example = "")
    @NotNull
    private String deviceId;

    @Schema(title = "name")
    @NotNull
    private String deviceName;
}
```

I have tried toString() like this:

```
public String toString(){
        return key+": "+ value;
    }
```

could not work.

Comment: have you tried overriding the toString() method ?

Comment: any docs about the toString() method? @azro

Comment: You didn't ever see the `toString` method ? https://www.javatpoint.com/understanding-toString()-method

Comment: I have tried tostring() but it still not work.@azro